# CSS Line Height, not working?

Tags: css

Trying to get a result that will outline the well .outline class, but its much too closely spaced together, and when I try and using the following code in my .intro class.

```
.intro {
    /** Text Formatting **/
    text-align: center;

    /** Line Spacing **/
    line-height: 3em;
}
```

The result I get is still the same as I would have if I wasn't using the line-height.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="intro"> <h4> In my <span class="outline">corner</span> of the internet I make messes that some how turn into code. Don't ask me <span class="outline">how</span>, don't ask me <span class="outline">corner</span>, but things just look good and work well.</h4> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outline {
     /** Styling **/
     background: #ff00f6;
     color: #FFF;

     /** Margin & Padding **/
     margin: 3px;
     padding: 6px 8px;
}
```

Comment: what you want to do???

Comment: Seems to [work](http://jsfiddle.net/doL9u7tq/).

Comment: You want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/6f3qzj5f/)?

Comment: When put to SO Snippet, it's working fine

Comment: @Vucko that seems to have fixed it, can you reply properly so I can set the answer to correct?

Comment: @Twipply I just c/p your markup and styles. Inspect the element, something is overriding your `line-height`.

Comment: @Vucko it appeared to be that h4 that was overriding it :)

Answer (score 3):

The code which you have mentioned seems to be working fine. I can see one issue, may be your css is being conflicted with `line-height`. Try to put `!important` with css as mentioned below:

```
.intro {
    /** Text Formatting **/
    text-align: center;

    /** Line Spacing **/
    line-height: 3em !important;
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/spidercode/9dLdp1z1/2/)**</kbd>